# How to I solve the no debug extension loaded in PhpStorm

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

[image: Screen shot]

I downloaded Xdebug 2.6.2

etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini

I am using Ubuntu 18

```
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

But not validating ...

After validation completed how do I debug the program?

Comment: Try adding `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`

Comment: i solved that error but how to break the program in debugging mode which local url i can give